# What is the difference between Angular CLI and quickstart?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have been watching some videos that related to angularJS 2, but i would like to know What is the difference between Angular CLI and quickstart?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Angular-CLI** is a TOOL to create your angular 2 application.  It provides commands to generate code such as components, services and directives to make angular 2 development easier to the  developer.  It also allows you to build your application and serve your application as you are developing.

**Angular 2 Quick Start** is a TUTORIAL to create a simple Angular 2 app. The Quick Start also has a Plunkr (code) that the developer can use to try out some ideas with Angular 2. Just like the name says it... it quickly gets you going with Angular 2.

For a real angular 2 application you will be using the Angular-CLI since it provides the tools (commands) you need for your development. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The CLI is used to start an Angular 2 application, and add new components, directives, and services, from the command line; it builds application “scaffolding” based on your input. It lets you add code, and unit tests, to an application quickly. Afterward, you fill in the actual business code.

The quick start is just a pre-coded application to give you an idea of what you can do with Angular 2 without having to write any code of you own.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of frameworks are providing productivity command-line interface tools(CLI) in bootstrapping a project , creating components, or downloading/installing packages or dependencies. It's very handy and quick to use in the console/terminal of the IDE or at the OS (Mac OS, Windows, Linux). That's why we see commands like `npm install, brew install, npm start, yo web-project-name`,  etc. In that regard, the angular team has developed the angular cli to follow that pattern to stay consistent and to improve productivity. It's still in beta so expect some changes. For latest updates and usage of the tool you can follow them in github https://github.com/angular/angular-cli