# What is difference between angularjs and angular cli?

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

There are 2 things available in angular :
1.angular cli
2.angularjs

please describe briefly. thanks

Comment: You can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965296/what-is-the-difference-between-angular-cli-and-quickstart) for underestanding differene

Answer (score 11):

**Angular-cli** a command line interface. and it helps to add new components, directives, and services, from the command line; 
it builds application based on your input. you can add code, test cases via command itself...

**AngularJS** is a structural framework for dynamic web apps. It lets you use HTML as your template language and lets you extend HTML's syntax to express your ... you need angularjs library to develop application

Answer (score 6):

**Angular-CLI** is a TOOL to create your angular 2 application. It provides commands to generate code such as components, services and directives to make angular 2 development easier to the developer. It also allows you to build your application and serve your application as you are developing.

**AngularJS** : Is the famous JavaScript based framework.

***Resume*** : In general we install Angular-CLI globally to help us in initialization or modification of our Angular projects

Answer (score 6):

In a very simple words,

**Angular CLI** is a command line interface for writing or easily setting/building up an angular application.

Its just like building a java application from a simple notepad (even though we have other IDEs to help)

**Angular js** - is a older version of Angular (version 1.x) which is a open-source JavaScript-based front-end web application framework.

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS is a structural framework for dynamic web apps. It lets you use HTML as your template language and lets you extend HTML's syntax to express your application's components clearly and succinctly.It controlls the code to what it actually to do...

Angular CLI is "Command Line Interface".it needs command to run and perform any operations and it is mandatory for angular 2 and not for angular 1.

The CLI is used to start an Angular 2 application, and add new components, directives, and services, from the command line; it builds application “scaffolding” based on your input. It lets you add code, and unit tests, to an application quickly. Afterward, you fill in the actual business code.

The quick start is just a pre-coded application to give you an idea of what you can do with Angular 2 without having to write any code of you own.

Answer (score 0):

Angualrjs- is nothing but just angular package which you can install in your system for further development.
Angular-cli- comes up with additional feature to make developer life easy it basically create a boilerplate code for you 
for ex: structure of your project and you want to add ant component class or service class in project so you can point to your directory and run this command 
**"ng generate service [name]"** it will automatically create a service class for you with initial configuration.